# Column index out of range when creating alias with criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, indexing, hibernate-criteria

Ok so I get this weird issue that I can't fix. 
I have 3 entities ( i will write things that only matters imo)

```
@Data
@Entity // all @ are in javax
@Table(name = "a", schema = "pl")
@SequenceGenerator(...)
public class A extends BaseEntity {
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.a")
    private Set<ABRel> Bs = new HashSet<ABRel>();
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "a_b_rel", schema = "pl")
public class ABRel implements IEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private OfferOrderProjectRelId pk;

    public OfferOrderProjectRel(B b, A a) {
        if (a == null || b == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("B orA equals null");
        }
        B.addA(this); // this methods just adds ABRel to sets in A and B
        A.addB(this);
        pk = new ABRelId(b, a);
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class OfferOrderProjectRelId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B b;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private A a;

    public ABRelId(B b, A a) {
        setB(b);
        setA(a);
    }
}

@Data
@Entity (it has javax import)
@Table(name = "b", schema = "pl")
@SequenceGenerator(...)
public class B extends BaseEntity {
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.b")
 private Set<ABRel> As = new HashSet<ABRel>();

@NotBlank
@Length(max = 10000)
@Column(name = "type", length = 10000, nullable = false)
private String type;
}
```

ABRel and ABRelId have private contructor (`ABRel()` and `ABRelId()`) but not sure if it matters. Entities are working just fine, so I don't think somethink is wrong with them but meaby I am wrong.

So I'm tryin to add criteria by B.type for my filters. Criteria are made "in" (not sure how to say it :) ) A.class. So here's criteria that I'm tryin to add in my dao ( I can add this to criteria not detached one if someone ask):

```
DetachedCriteria idCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class, "a");
idCriteria.createAlias("Bs", "btype", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("Bs.pk.B.type", "someType"));
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(A.class, "a");
criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("id", idCriteria));
```

What I am tryin to achieve is to get all ABRels that have some specified B.type, then I will have to count it somehow, but this is not my issue atm. I have to use criteria, can't use any HQL. I also read that hibernate has some kind of bug with creating alias beetwen entity and its embedded so I can't make it too (probably thats why I am having to much trouble with it). So any ideas? I'm running out of option so any help would be great!

I almost forget, I'm getting this error

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unknown entity: null    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getPropertyMapping(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:638)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getType(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:587)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getTypeUsingProjection(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:569)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getTypedValue(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:627)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.criterion.SimpleExpression.getTypedValues(SimpleExpression.java:100)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getQueryParameters(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:335)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.criterion.SubqueryExpression.createAndSetInnerQuery(SubqueryExpression.java:151)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.criterion.SubqueryExpression.toSqlString(SubqueryExpression.java:68)

UPDATE:

I have added sth like this

```
criteria.createAlias("As", "oorel", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
criteria.createAlias("oorel.pk.b", "order", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("type", "order"));
```

And now I'm getting new error(it's in my native language so i will try to translate it) its postgres and hibernate exception :

> Column index out of range: 1, number of columns: 0

Sorry for my bad english and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunetly a hibernate bug which havent been fixed yet. This error appears because hibernate is not able to create alias via entity that contains composite key.